# (non) linear regression on graphs with multiple y per x values

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mean, excel, fallacy

I have a data set with multiple y values per x value. Using Excel the scatter plot and the regression line tools, I wish to apply regression on the data to determine if there is any connection between the data points.

If I just pick the regression trend line (Layout 3) in Excel, it gives me a line with an R² value of 0.02, but if I pick the average y-values for each x-value, and use the trend line on them, I get a trend line with an R² value of 0,963 which, pardon my phrasing, looks correct.

My question is; Is it safe to use a set of averaged y-values in order to limit it to a single y-value per x-value?

Comment: You might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy, which applies here.

Comment: Consider this strategy: average your averages, but keeping two distinct x values. With any luck, your y values will differ. Now what is your $R^2$? Correct or not, the key point is that you changed your regression problem to a different regression problem. The more you average, the more variability you eliminate. Feature and bug, all in one.

Comment: An example in which a scientist's claims were wholly discredited due to the use of average values in a regression is documented in this [2007 EFSA Review](http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/doc/19r.pdf). For recent (amazing) developments see http://retractionwatch.com/2013/11/28/controversial-seralini-gmo-rats-paper-to-be-retracted/: the same scientist misused statistical analyses so badly that six French scientific academies joined to denounce his work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**, it is not, **you should not do that**.

Copied from comments:

> You might be interested in
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy, which applies here.

– whuber

> Consider this strategy: average your averages, but keeping two
> distinct x values. With any luck, your y values will differ. Now what
> is your R2? Correct or not, the key point is that you changed your
> regression problem to a different regression problem. The more you
> average, the more variability you eliminate. Feature and bug, all in
> one.

– Nick Cox
( If you think of Nick Cox' example as a t-test comparing two groups, the fallacy becomes very clear )

> An example in which a scientist's claims were [wholly discredited due
> to the use of average values in a regression is documented in this](https://efsa.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.2903/j.efsa.2007.19r)
> For [recent (amazing) developments see](https://retractionwatch.com/2013/11/28/controversial-seralini-gmo-rats-paper-to-be-retracted/)
> the same scientist misused statistical analyses so badly that six
> French scientific academies joined to denounce his work.

– whuber