# Is redundancy/correlation between fixed and random effects a problem in mixed-effect models?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

This might seem a stupid question but I can't find an clear answer.

Say I am studying **Species richness** (outcome variable) in lakes. I have data from **20 lakes, over 4 years, and 3 values per year(early, mid, and late summer)**.
It is clear to me that **LakeID** should be a **random factor**, whatever the model I consider, to account for pseudoreplication as samples from the same lake are likely correlated.

Now, I would like to see, amongst others, if the area of the lake (its size, termed **Lake_area**) influences Species richness. I wanted to put it as a **fixed effect**.

The model would be:

```
lme(Richness ~ Lake_area + 1|LakeID)
```

Is this correct to do so?

- On the one hand, I feel this is redundant, as one lake has only one size (one area, it does not change over the study period). And by including LakeID as a random effect, I somehow take into account variation on richness due to variation between lakes.
- On the other hand, (i)doing a model comprising only Lake_area as a fixed effect, no random factor would be surely wrong, as it would fail to consider that some samples are not independent.
  (ii) while Lake_area is somehow "nested" in Lake, Lake_area does not explain all the variation which is due to LakeID. Depth, morphometry, catchment, light exposition, etc are all potentially playing a role, that I do not necessarily capture with Lake_area.  (iii) if I want to do a more complex model (which I do, I will have time in julian_days as a fixed effect and likely other variables), I have to include LakeID as a random factor in my final model.

One solution I see to test the effect of lake_area is to take the average richness per lake as the outcome variable, and fit this model

```
 lm(Mean(Richness_per_lake)~Lake_area)
```

But I lose power and I can't do that if I want to include other variables.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, while reading Ben Bolker's GLMM FAQ, I cam across a section referring to a [blog post] (https://www.muscardinus.be/2017/08/fixed-and-random/) from Thierry Onkelinx that answers my question. 
It says that you can include a variable both as a fixed and random factor if and only if it is discrete. In my case, as Lake_area is discrete, the model Richness ~ Lake_area + (1|Lake_area) would be valid. 
I think then that Richness ~ Lake_area + (1|LakeID) would work too, as to one lakeID there is a single value of Lake_area nad vice_versa.  (ctd..)

Comment: (..Ctd) However, while the estimates and p-values are similar with both models (lme function of nlme package), they are not exactly the same. 

Don't know what I'm missing here

Comment: PS: taking the mean per group and then doing regression is not recommended. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78451/non-linear-regression-on-graphs-with-multiple-y-per-x-values

Comment: I found a similar question and based on the answers it is OK and even recommended to use the group-level variable such as lake size as a fixed effect https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284314/fixed-effect-that-is-constant-inside-each-of-the-random-groups-in-a-mixed-model

Comment: This question is also related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223439/use-of-variables-at-the-group-level-in-linear-mixed-models